# Delete a group of Dicom tags at once

Tags: fo-dicom

I have a dicom sequence that contains several “Item” (fffe,e000).

Each item contains two tags  (300a,004a) & (300a,00b8)

One of the tags (type string -has a value of “xyz”)  I want to remove belongs inside the "item" group
[image]

I would like to delete entire "item".

This is what I have tried so far

//look for specific string e.g. “xyz”

```
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
```

{

```
    if(tagName == "xyz")
```

{

```
//tag found , now remove complete item ()

 var remove = DicomTag.Parse("300a,004a");

 openedDicom.Dataset.Remove(remove);

openedDicom.Save(Path.Combine(dirPath, "Test.dcm"));
```

}}

Is there a better way to do this rather than one at a time, basically remove complete Item, only the correct item?

Comment: This should be possible, see for example [this question](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/discussions/1701) or [this one](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/discussions/1685).